# EntityManager injected by Spring but null on first use

Tags: spring, jpa

I am just working on a basic webapp that implements spring + hibernate entitymanager

I set up my dao and context exactly as described by this post: 
http://blog.springsource.com/2006/08/07/using-jpa-in-spring-without-referencing-spring/

And created a test for it as shown here:
http://lstierneyltd.com/blog/development/examples/unit-testing-spring-apps-with-runwithspringjunit4classrunner-class/

For some reason when I try to access the entitymanager for creating a query, its null.

However from setting a breakpoint inside the setter method for the entitymanager I can see that Spring is injecting it correctly, and the field is being initialized.

Any clue as to why the entitymanager might be getting nullified after the setter has returned ?

Edit: 
The dao code where I am setting the breakpoint:

```
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

private EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this. entityManager = entityManager;
}

public Collection loadProductsByCategory(String category) {
    return entityManager.createQuery("from Product p where p.category = :category")
        .setParameter("category", category).getResultList();
}
}
```

Comment: Please can we see the code that is attempting to use the Entity Manager. Are you sure that you're looking at the same object instance when you breakpoint the setter?

Comment: @Alex I added the code above, I am setting the breakpoint in setEntityManager().  The local (this.entityManager) is null but the parameter value it is being set to has been initialized correctly. The local variable however goes back to null when I break inside the loadProductsByCategory() method

Comment: Can we also see the test which is using this DAO?

Comment: What version of Spring? (And a tutorial from 6yrs ago?!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<tx:annotation-driven/>` that I presume you do have, tells Spring to put transactional advice on any class or method that has an `@Transactional` annotation on it.

Transactions should be defined on the Service/Business layer, hence your `ProductDaoImpl` is usually called from within a service, which *will* have `@Transactional`. e.g.

```
pubic class ProductService {

    @Resource(...)   // inject it the way you like e.g. @Autowired / Setter / Constructor injection, etc..
    ProductDao yourProductDao;

    @Transactional
    public List<Product> findCarProducts {
        yourProductDao.loadProductsByCategory( "car" );
    }
}
```

*(alternatively, you can use an XML based transaction configuration)*

Now the actual call to your DAO will be `within` a transaction => which is very important for entityManager / Hibernate Session. Otherwise you'll see all the usual errors: e.g. entityManager is null, entityManager is closed, etc..

In case you'd like to test a DAO in solo, you have to make sure that your test case is wrapped within a transaction via `@TransactionConfiguration`. For example, if your transaction manager bean is defined as:

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Your DAO test would include this bean name:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txManager", defaultRollback=false)
public class ProductDaoTransactionalTests {
    // your use cases here..
}
```

You can read more about transactional tests in [Spring Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#testing-tx)

Comment: also, since you are using multiple examples to follow, make sure all your context files are imported into a single app context that you load in your test.

Comment: Bah, feel very stupid, I had an @Transactional on the actual DAO class, and removing that + moving it to the test fixed the issue. Thanks!